# Lock a front-end access database

Tags: ms-access

I've recently split my database and have two front end versions. One version for data entry and one version for end-users to run their own queries. Is there a way to "lock" the query version so that end-users cannot accidentally change data from the queries they run? I.e., I only want them to be able to run select queries and make table queries. I don't want them to be able to edit any of the data from the back end file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set the queries as snapshots, distinct, or aggregating.

But it is not 100% safe, indeed not if they have access to the linked tables.

To be safe, move the database to an SQL Server (Express version is free) and create a read-only user account.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to create a front end database just for these users. Copy the queries over and create a Navigation Form with sub-forms that point at those queries. Set the Locked data property to [yes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRRNN.jpg) and then set your [database options menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9hhM.jpg) so they don't have access to the Navigation Pane or the editing menus. Its not totally secure but it will prevent the average user from changing data.